# SprinBoot additional dynamic configurations to support different business logics

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, configuration

I need to implement this scenario into a SpringBoot microservice:

In order to support multiple business logic that are based on different configurations for each supported logic, I would like to use a dynamic configuration set.

As an idea, suppose that it's necessary to support a lot of different configurations where each configuration presents the same set of parameters with, obviously, different values.

I'm just able to image this as json, something like this:

```
{
"configurations": [{
        "client": "client_1",
        "parameterA": "x",
        "parameterB": "y",
        "parameterC": "z"
    },
    {
        "client": "client_2",
        "parameterA": "x2",
        "parameterB": "y2",
        "parameterC": "z2"
    },
    {
        "client": "client_3",
        "parameterA": "x3",
        "parameterB": "y3",
        "parameterC": "z3"
    },
    ...
]
```

}

Suppose that I'll put this json into my project. When the service starts, the json config file will be loaded in order to load the configurations list in memory. The idea is to create a custom `@Configuration` in order to have some utility methods to read the configurations values (eg. `getConfigurationByClient`).

Do you think that this could be a good way?

Are there some different best practices to implement similar requirements?

I'm not able to find similar examples or articles in order to understand if this could be a good approach.

Comment: I have used this approach many times, but with a different configuration syntax and with command-line applications rather than micro services. In my experience, the approach works well. Whenever my application would use just one of the several supplied configuration sets per run, then I would give my application two command-line arguments: one argument to specify the name of the configuration file, and another argument to specify the name of the scope (within the configuration file) containing the desired configuration variables, for example `-cfg example.cfg -scope client_2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest it depends on frequency of this values getting changed. If frequency is too low, and you are okay with deploying your entire application to change some of the values, then it's fine I guess to keep json in your project.

But if you have some requirement to change it every month or in some interval, I would suggest to have this file at remote location and have service pull json(not feasible for low latency if associated to some REST endpoint) and load it in your service to do following task.

Other better approach would be to persist it in DB (RDBMS table etc), where you can change this values directly and app service can query the latest param values from DB and perform the bussiness logic.